# DIV is visually getting nested in previous DIV

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Either I am staring at my screen for way too long and just can't see it or I can't tell what what I am doing wrong.

This should be pretty straight forward, but the `id="parkEntrances"` title DIV is getting positioned in the `id="featureDisplay"` above it.  So as the Amenities are listed, the Entrances title bar is appearing behind the image icons. But when I look at the rendered code in Chrome Inspector, it shows the `ENTRANCES` title bar outside the `featureDisplay` DIV tags.

In Chrome Inspector, when I hover mouse over the `id="featureDisplay"` code, the visual screen shows a div title tag of: `div#featureDisplay 324px x 0px` - so I think this is contributing to the problem.  Why its 0px height though baffles me because the feature icons that get listed all show up and are 50px height...it lists two rows of icons so the height of `featureDisplay` should be default be 100px...and when I manually change the div height to 110px, everything lines up the way its supposed to.  but this isn't require for the other sections with identical formating.

Its like the `featureDisplay is unaware of its own contents.

Its the pretty much the same code, but I can't figure out why Entrances keeps getting nested up in Amenities section. ....The other sections 'INSTRUCTIONS' and `PHOTOS` are positioned just fine.

```
<div id="fullScreen">
  <div class="customBar" >GENERAL INFO</div>
  <div style="margin-left:10px;font-weight:bolder;font-size:14px;">Location: {{park.address}},{{park.city}}
    <br>Price: {{park.currency}}{{park.price}}
    <br>Name: {{park.location_name}}
  </div>

  <div id="parkFeatures" class="customBar" ng-if="park.features.length == 0">AMENITIES: None Listed</div>
  <div id="parkFeatures" class="customBar" ng-if="park.features.length > 0">AMENITIES</div>
    <div id="featureDisplay" ng-if="park.features.length > 0" style="display:block;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">
      <div id="feature_{{feature.key}}" ng-repeat="feature in park.features" style="text-align:center;width:20%;float:left;"> 
        <img ng-src="{{getIcon(feature.key)}}" style="height:50px;" on-hold="hoverName('{{feature.name}}',1)" on-release="hoverName('',0)" />
      </div>
    </div>

  <div id="parkEntrances" class="customBar" ng-if="park.entrances.length == 0">ENTRANCES: None Listed</div>
  <div id="parkEntrances" class="customBar" ng-if="park.entrances.length > 0">ENTRANCES</div>
    <div id="entranceDisplay" ng-if="park.entrances.length > 0" style="display:block;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">
      <div id="moreEntrances" ng-repeat="entrance in park.entrances" style="">
        Lat: {{entrance.coordinates[0]}}, Lon: {{entrance.coordinates[1]}}
      </div>
    </div>

  <div id="parkInstructions"  class="customBar" ng-if="park.instructions.length == 0">INSTRUCTIONS: None Listed</div>
  <div id="parkInstructions" class="customBar" ng-if="park.instructions > 0">INSTRUCTIONS</div>
    <div id="instructionsDisplay" ng-if="park.instructions > 0" style="display:block;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">
      <div id="moreInstructions" ng-repeat="instruction in park.instructions" style="">
        {{instruction.instructions}}
      </div>      
    </div>

  <div id="parkPhotos" class="customBar" ng-if="park.photos.length == 0">IMAGES: None Listed</div>
  <div id="parkPhotos" class="customBar" ng-if="park.photos.length > 0">IMAGES: None Listed</div>
    <div id="photosDisplay" ng-if="park.photos.length > 0" style="display:block;width:90%;margin-left:5%;margin-right:5%;">
      <div id="morePhotos" ng-repeat="photo in park.photos" >
        <img ng-src="{{photo.url}}" />
      </div>      
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Can we have the javascript as well ?

Comment: I figured it out.  I was using `display:block` - and when I changed it to `display:inline-block` the Entrances section dropped down to where it should be.  Not certain I understand the difference between the two....going to go do some reading now.  Can't believe how much time I wasted on this.

Comment: You have several elements with the same id e.g. `id="moreEntrances" ng-repeat="entrance in park.entrances"`.  Should this say `.length`. `ng-if="park.instructions > 0"`?

Comment: Yeah, I did catch that too. Thanks.  I had also cleaned up the IDs for the ng-repeats too.